# Python: How do you make an area code finder?

Tags: python-2.7, raw-input

```
def areacode():
    code={}
    cont='Yes'
    while cont == 'Yes':
        num=int(raw_input('Type in a zip code:')
        if num==407:
            print "Found in Florida"
        elif num==718:
            print "Found in New York"
        elif num==201:
            print "Found in New Jersey"
        elif num==408:
            print "Found in California"
        else:
            print "Zip code not found."
        cont=raw_input("Would you like to continue? Yes or No?: ")
```

I am stuck on how to continue and what to do next. I know what I have is not much, but any direction as to where to go on next would be nice. How would I make this into a nested dictionary?

And there happens to be an error in my if statement, it's telling me that there is an invalid syntax. I don't seem to see what's wrong though.

Comment: Maybe try restating the question that your professor wants you to answer in this assignment and clear it up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have a good start and a few options ahead of you.

Make sure you're reading the proper documentation when you look at the following advice.

1.) You could check the site's information in real time. I wouldn't recommend this method as, though it is facilitated in Python, it's still the most difficult option and, at your presumed level, I'd assume it's overkill.

If you wanted to go this route however, I would check [here](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html) for more information -- there's a module to help you out!

2.) Grab the data yourself, stick it in a text file ([or CSV, which is a type of data file prime for this type of activity](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html)) and then have your program grab data from the text file. It's much easier to grab information in the format you want when you're doing the "heavy lifting" as it were, of getting the information from the website. I'd suggest this method because the state-zip code relation is not likely to change in the time span that you'll be using this program.

3.) Hardcode the zip code - state combinations. This is not recommended and would take a very, very, long time.

Basically, your options are between difficulty in coding and difficulty at run time. 3 is the longest to code, but the easiest to use (don't do 3). 1 is the theoretically easiest (when talking about program length) to code but the hardest to run (as it has to grab the data each time).

I would, as you've probably gathered, suggest 2. Take the data how you want it, put it in a text file in the same folder as the program, and use [this documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html) to get you in the right direction.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much, this has helped make it clear as to what I should do. I would go on with choice number 2 as you have suggested.

Comment: No problem! I would check to make sure that method is okay for homework before going ahead. Make sure the check my answer off if it's the answer to your question so that this question becomes closed!

Comment: Okay, so as I looked more into your method I realized that my professor has not taught us this. I tried to self-teach it, but it's actually quite confusing.

Comment: I'm guessing at this point that your professor wants you as a user to enter in zip-code state combinations? Because that is way different than what I had in mind haha

Comment: Haha, my professor asked us to just have the user input a zip code and then the function will display what state the zip code is from using a nested dictionary.

Comment: Did your professor specify that you needed to hard-code the nested dictionary or are you supposed to grab the data from a web page?

Comment: My professor just stated that I need to have nested dictionaries or lists for states with multiple area codes and I can refer to areacode.org for area codes. The function should include a parameter for the area code as raw input from the user and print back to the user the state where the zip code is from.

Comment: I believe he wants you to simply hard-code the zip codes, using the website as guidance. Good luck!